# Want formula to return a number value or blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet, formula

I have two columns (A & B) of information. I'm trying to create a third (C) with the answer of B divided by A in the form of a percentage or if 100% a blank or dash (-). Below is an example.

I've tried several different formula combinations like `=IF((B38/A38)<100,(B38/A38)," ")` I can get the percentage answers okay but have not been able to get the wanted result of a blank or a dash.

```
**A**  **B**    **C**  
1.99    0.99    49.7%  
1.99    1.99      
3.99    3.99    -  
2.99    1.99    66.6%
```

Thank you for any help given.

Answer (score 1):

100% displayed as an integer is 1, so you want `=IF(B1/A1=1,"-",B1/A1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the desired result for the `blank` because the statement is always true. replace 100 by 100%-

```
=IF((B38/A38)<100%,(B38/A38),"")
```